# Create JSON ArrayList/JSON object and send to PHP in Android

Tags: java, php, android, json, arraylist

i have Two String ArrayList in JAVA(Question,Answer).I have to put these two array list with in one JSONobject or JSONArraylist and need to Send as a json object or arraylist to php.There i have to Iterate two array lists one by one.

i want to get json object or arraylist like

```
$array1=array(2, 4);\\First Requested array
$array2=array(5, 96);\\Second Requested array
$array = array(
    'r1' =>$array1 ,
    'r2' => $array2,

    );
```

I don't know how to put two arrays with in a arraylist or object..

my ArrayList is

```
ArrayList<String> Questions = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> Answers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I don't know how to put two arrays in one arraylist and how to send,receive json object .

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
ArrayList<String> Questions = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> Answers = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> Q&A = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONObject send = new JSONObject;

    JSONObject jo;
    for (int i = 0; i < your_arrayList.size(); i++) {
       jo = new JSONObject(); // when to loop start it will prom a new JSONObject
       jo.put("STRING_NAME", "FIRST_ARRAYLIST".get[i]); // get your arrayList index
       jo.put("STRING_NAME", "SECOND_ARRAYLIST".get[i]); // get your arrayList index

       Q&A.add(jo.toString()); // pass the JSONObject into your arrayList
    }
    send.put("STRING_NAME", Q&A); //pass your arrayList in your JSONObject
```

then send it using your method :) hope this will help if you have arrayList in your method you can send Q&A, if you need jsonObject you can send the send JSONObject

Comment: what is the exact output do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
$array1=array(2, 4);\\First Requested array
$array2=array(5, 96);\\Second Requested array
$array['arrayList'] = array('r1' =>$array1 ,'r2' => $array2); 

$jsonString = json_encode($array);
echo $jsonString;
```

Comment: i have created two arraylist in java . i need to convert that as json object

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    ArrayList<String> Questions = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Answers = new ArrayList<String>();

    JSONArray finalJson = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < Questions.size(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            json.put("Question", Questions.get(i);

            finalJson.put(json);

    }

    JSONArray finalJson1 = new JSONArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < Answers.size(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            json.put("Answer", Answers.get(j);

            finalJson1.put(json);

    }

JSONObject resultjson = new JSONObject();
resultjson.put("Questions", finalJson);
resultjson.put("Answers", finalJson1);
```

If you want to upload json to server below example will help you

http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/sending-json-data-to-server-using-async-thread/

resultjson is

```
{
"Questions": [
    {
        "Question":"...."
    },
    {
        "Question":"...."
    },
    {
        "Question":"...."
    }
    ],

"Answers": [
    {
       "Answer":"...."
    },
    {
       "Answer":"...."
    },
    {
       "Answer":"...."
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i followed your code.but i don't know in which format i will get json data in php .pls help me...

Comment: Bro i just want array like $array1=array(2, 4);$array2=array(5, 96); in php.

Comment: First Array(Question1,question2,....) Second Array(Answer1,Answer2,...)

Answer (score -1):

use `json_encode()` as below.`json_encode()` is use to convert your array into json string.

```
$array = array(
    'r1' =>$array1 ,
    'r2' => $array2,

    );
$json = json_encode($array);
echo $json;
```

For more see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php